# "Time of (the) day"

Tags: definite-articles, zero-article

I am confused about the article usage in the phrase "time of (the) day".

From my research, I understand that "time of day" (*day* with the zero article) is more common and probably more idiomatic. It's also a part of an idiom [not give somebody the time of day](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80338/whats-the-origin-of-the-idiom-dont-give-it-the-time-of-day/). But I'm interested in its more literal usage and sense.

Is there any difference in usage or meaning between "time of day" and "time of **the** day".

I went to the COCA for examples but I still haven't been able to come up with any reasoning when to prefer one over the other:

With *the*:

> What's your biggest vice? - Dark chocolate. I'll have it at any *time of *the* day*; it's never too
>   early or too late.

Without **the**:

> These morning menu favorites taste good any *time of day*

Comment: The second example is incorrect -- it uses the phrase, not the idiom and so should include the definite article.

Comment: It's possibly as simple as a UK / US slewing. Ellipses tend to be more common (and in some cases more acceptable) in the US; they are generally seen as a more informal register in the UK. I'd say the alternatives are quite interchangeable in the examples you've picked, unless you add "said Lady Penelope".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is saying that *any time of day* is ungrammatical, I have to disagree. Both it and *any time of **the** day* can refer to an unspecified point on any day. Additionally, *any time of **the** day* can refer to an unspecified point on a particular day.

Comment: Yeah, I also got surprised by other people's answers as they were not what I expected. I think I can find hundreds of examples of this 'ungrammatical' usage by native speakers. If native speakers can't use articles correctly, then should I give up learning them now? :)

Comment: Cobuild have a monograph on the usages of the articles in English. It runs to over 100 pages. Few native speakers have even heard of it, never mind read it (_I_ haven't tracked down a copy yet). If you get one first, you can study it and then tell _us_ how we're supposed to use the things.